# Execute a shell script after maven-surefire-plugin tests results

Tags: java, shell, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I am trying to execute a shell script that sends our testing results to 3rd party.
We are running the tests in Jenkins pipeline, and the tests are running via Cucumber.
Also, we are using maven-surefire-plugin to run the tests, and exec-maven-plugin to execute the shell script.

The expected flow is:

1. Jenkins pipeline run a "mvn install" command
2. maven-surefire-plugin runs all the tests
3. Regardless of the tests results (success/failure) a shell script will be executed and it will get the report file and upload it to a 3rd party software

However, it looks like that if one of the tests failed, the exec-maven-plugin doesn't execute shell script. Meaning, step 3 doesn't succeed.

Here is a partial POM.xml file of the module:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>cucumber-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>none</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                          <include>**/*CucumberRunner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Shell Script</id>
                            <phase>----some phase------</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>wsl</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>sh</argument>
                                    <argument>-c</argument>
                                    <argument>${PWD}/src/test/resources/scripts/shellScript.sh</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Every time we use the command:

```
mvn -B install -P cucumber-tests
```

The surefire plugin runs the tests, and if everything passes the shell script also being executed (phases that we've tested are "test", "integration-test" and "verify"), but if something fails, maven doesn't execute the script.

We've also tried skipping tests (doesn't help because the result is Successful), using -fae/--fail-at-end flag (did nothing) and running a java code instead of shell script, but nothing worked so far.

Is what we're trying to achieve even possible? Are we missing something?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in Maven? You have a CI pipeline from which you can do this?

Comment: Yes. We are trying to get this process automated as part of our CI

Comment: So you are using Jenkins for you CI. You can add steps in your CI that run after your run maven. That would probably the better place to upload the report.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore test failures you can use:

```
mvn -B install -P cucumber-tests  -D"maven.test.failure.ignore=true"
```

But as it explains in the documentation:

> Set this to "true" to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.
>
> https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't quite work for me because the build status is still success but I need it to be failure.

Comment: You can't do that. You have to add an extra step in your CI then, not in your Maven execution.